# Как часто на практике используется Hash? (C# Backend)

Tags: c#, хеширование, backend

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как часто используются hash\хэширующие функции в разработке и в каких ситуациях вам пришлось с этим работать?
Дело в том, что в своём курсе сильно застопорился на хэшах, никак не могу добить эту тему. Хотел бы пойти дальше и вернуться позже, после уменьшения потока информации или при конкретной задаче, но опасаюсь, что это важная тема.

Comment: Невозможно дать объективный ответ

Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что вы имеете в виду функцию `GetHashCode`, которая есть у каждого объекта в .NET.

---

Непосредственно данная функция используется довольно редко. Однако, она используется часто *косвенно*, когда ваш объект попадает в качестве ключа в `Dictionary`, `HashSet`, или группируется в LINQ (`GroupBy` или там `Distinct`).

Для начала, вам про хэш достаточно знать следующее:

- Одинаковые объекты должны иметь одинаковые хеши

  - Но не наоборот! Если хэши одинаковые, то объекты не обязаны быть одинаковыми
- Функция `GetHashCode`, если уж и вызывается, то много раз подряд, поэтому она должна быть быстрой
- Хэшкод объекта не должен (!) меняться, если/пока объект служит ключом в `HashSet`/`Dictionary`.

  - Поэтому не стоит использовать мутирующие объекты в качестве ключей. Или стоит, но нужно хорошо понимать, что вы делаете.
- Обычно для вычисления хэшкода объекта используют комбинацию из хэшкодов полей, это выглядит как [`HashCode.Combine(f1, f2, f3, ...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode.combine?view=net-5.0)

  - Сумма или там XOR хэш-кодов полей хуже по многим причинам
  - Если содержимое поля не является логической частью объекта, не включайте его в вычисление хэшкода. Например, если вы держите в поле ссылку на какой-нибудь внешний объект, который может поменять хэш-код сам по себе.

Более глубокие знания по идее можно «добить» и попозже.

Answer (score 2):

Очень часто, а вернее, практически всегда, используется хеширование паролей. Как только вам понадобится хранить информацию о пользователях, сразу возникнет вопрос: как это сделать надёжно? Тут-то хеши и понадобятся.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы планируете использовать ваши объекты, например, в качестве ключей словаря, то качественная хэш-функция просто *must have*, иначе у вас будет много коллизий и ваш словарь вместо `O(1)` будет показывать гораздо более худшую производительность.

Ну и если вы кладёте объекты в `HashSet`, например.